# merge [publications] and [papers] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have two separate tags for [publications](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publications) and [papers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papers). As far as I can tell, they're identical; both discuss research articles. I propose to merge them, but just in case I'm missing some nuance, I wanted to bring it up here first.

Comment: From what I saw in the current questions, I agree that they are similar, and could be merged.

Comment: Similarly: I found that the **[tag:writing] and [tag:scientific-writing] tags** are used interchangeably… I suggest we [make them synonyms](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/scientific-writing/synonyms)… if you agree, please go [vote](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/scientific-writing/synonyms) on that suggestion.

Comment: @F'x - Please post those as a separate post, and if no one objects, we can merge them manually. Mods have tools to set up tag aliases without requiring four votes (although you probably [know that](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/30/fx) [already](http://french.stackexchange.com/users/19/fx) :D )

Comment: @eykanal yeah, but I wanted to see if the community could gather enough votes for it… guess I'm not gonna hold my breath, though

Comment: @F'x - In a community this small, I doubt it. Even on the main SO site it can take months to get enough votes to set up a tag alias on some of the more obscure tags. It's just not something people look for.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that publications is broader than paper: a book chapter is a publication, it's not a paper. Probably, so is a popular science contribution (I've never heard those referred as “papers”, more like “pop sci articles”). Now, whether that difference is used in practice, I cannot say.

Comment: I can't say I've ever noticed people using the two tags differently.

Comment: A book is also a publication, not a paper.

Answer (score 1):

I agree.  I recommend that they be merged.  They are 99% overlapping, and in practice seem to be used more or less interchangeable.